# What is the best way to put content of uploaded by user CSV file into database

Tags: postgresql

What is the best way to insert the content of the file (.csv, up to 800 MBytes) uploaded by a web-application user into the PostgreSQL database?

I see three options:

- Insert statement for each file row
- Insert statement for multiple rows (insert batches containing e.g. 1000 rows)
- Store temp file, upload it using PostgreSQL COPY command (I have shared directory between servers where application and database located)

Which way is better? Or maybe there is any other way?

Additional details:

- I use Java 8 and JSP
- Database: PostgreSQL 9.5
- To handle multipart data I use Apache Commons FileUpload and Apache Commons CSV to parse the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely NOT a single insert for each row. Relaying on PostgreSQL COPY command should be the fastest option.